# Search Core Results Web Part Doesn't Display Managed Property

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am trying to display managed property (content type) in Search Core Results Web Part but it is not working.

```
I have created the Managed Property in CA
I have mapped it to content type
I have done a full crawl
I have checked the "Content Using this property" in CA 
I have added the column name in the tool panne and also the xslt code
```

(as described here: http://www.prosharepointsearch.com/?p=240)

but I still cannot see the managed property in the web part.

What else do I have to check?

Comment: Hi, you may be running into a bug see my previous answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617102/sharepoint-2010-search-result-file-icon-change

Comment: Hi Aquila, for the moment I found a solution to my problem by entering a query in the fixed keyword query. However, I find it strange why it does not work as people explain it in their blogs.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The link that I have posted above works correctly. In my opinion the problem with me was that I was copying the code from the site and pasting it in the Visual studio and that was causing problems. Mind you, I did the formatting of quotes like: (') and ("), but was not working.

**So the solution for me was to type it my self from scratch. That way it avoided any issues that copy and paste caused.**